# Cannot insert into eslaticsearch using spark and kafka with python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm integrating kafka and spark with elasticsearch.

when i run this script using :

```
sudo spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.3.1 --jars jars/elasticsearch-hadoop-2.1.0.Beta2.jar  cv.py localhost:9092 flumekafka
```

Script 'cv.py':

```
import json
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext 
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
#import org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="kafka")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)
    brokers, topic = sys.argv[1:]
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], 
       {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
    es_write_conf = {"es.nodes" : 'localhost',"es.port" : 
    '9200',"es.resource" : 'rh/cv',"es.input.json" : "yes"}

    parsed = kvs.map(lambda v: json.loads(v[1]))
   # rdd = sc.parallelize(kvs)
    #def format_data(x):
      #  return (data['doc_id'], json.dumps(data))

    #rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: format_data(x))
    parsed.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(path='-', 
    outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat", 
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable", 
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", 
    conf=es_write_conf)
    #parsed.pprint()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I got this problem :

```
parsed.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(path='-',  outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat", 
keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",   valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",   conf=es_write_conf)
AttributeError: 'KafkaTransformedDStream' object has no attribute 'saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile'
```

what can i do to make my script insert into elasticsearc or if is there an other solution.

Comment: you can use ‘saveToEs’ in spark for saving into Elasticsearch

Comment: saveToEs do not solve the problem in streaming in spark-submit import elasticsearch is not recognized even when i did pip install elasticsearch

Comment: https://github.com/TargetHolding/pyspark-elastic/blob/master/README.md you need this

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to do? Are you wanting to write data from Kafka into Elasticsearch?

Comment: i'm listening to some file with kafka , send data to spark then write it from spark into Elastcsearch. i'm using python as programming language.

Comment: and this is in dataframe, rdd or?

Comment: KafkaDStream
i found the solution i need to convert the input type kafkaDStream to RDD then insert into elasticsearch

Comment: @AliMtibaa may i know how you did that? Stuck with the same issue.